# Переклад англійського "Hey, dude!"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

[Dude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dude) - чоловік, хлопець (зазвичай звертання). Стильна та впевнена людина.

Не раз зустрічав, що перекладають це слово як "[чувак](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA)", однак такого слова немає в СУМі (якщо його там ввести, то відкриється сторінка із Вільного тлумачного словника, де слово "[чувак](http://sum.in.ua/f/chuvak)" має позначку "жарг."). А також у мене є підозри (через статтю із Вікіпедії), що це слово може бути запозиченим із російської мови.

Однак, більшість перекладачів (наприклад [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/dude?page=3&tmmode=MUST), [цей онлайн перекладач](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/en-uk/word-dude-translation#), Гугл) перекладають його як "чувак". Хоча на Глосбі ще зустрів такі цікаві варіанти як "волохатик" (можливо, якщо слово "dude" вживається у розмові між двома "хіпі", то такий варіант перекладу є прийнятним), "[пацан](http://sum.in.ua/s/pacan)" (вигук "Ей, пацан" звучить дещо незвично і як на мене може мати дещо негативний відтінок).

Цікавить як краще перекласти це слово і чи доречно буде використовувати для перекладу жаргонізм "чувак" (бо мені здається, що саме слово "dude" зазвичай вживається в розмовному стилі)? Чи може все ж таки використати інші варіанти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Привіт, хлопче." або "агов, хлопче"
(українські аналоги). 
Як жаргон: [чуваче](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA), [пацик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53407/375395.html). Також зустрічається в побуті "[друже](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on)" та "[приятель](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on)"(рідко)

---

Запропоновані варіанти зустрічаються в побуті, перекладах фільмів, аніме та деякої літератури(фанові переклади), крім як пацик та приятель ([НМД](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%9C%D0%A5%D0%9E)).

[Пацик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53407/375395.html) — файний хлопець; стукач; хлопець молодого віку.

[Приятель](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on) — гарний друг.

---

Мій словник пропонує жахливі варіанти(↓фотографія↓). Я рекомендую застосовувати "[привіт](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryvit)" або "[агов](http://sum.in.ua/s/aghov)". *А чому не "гей"?!* можуть не правильно зрозуміти.

[image]

Comment: Шчо не так з _гей_?

Comment: Дякую за редагування, виглядає краще. Долучаюсь до питання пана follower. Що не так з "гей"? Як на мене, це суто український, дуже автентичний вигук.